# Rice theorem could apply except RE language?

Tags: context-free, undecidability, rice-theorem, decidability

You know that Rice theorem is applicable to check decidability of RE language. Also we know that all regular, deterministic context free, context free, recursive languages are RE languages.

$Q_1:$ So my question is that could I apply Rice theorem to check decidability of for example emptiness, membership etc of CFL languages.

$Q_2:$ $$L_1= \{\langle M \rangle \mid \text{L(M) } = \phi\}$$ is undecidable for RE languages but $$L_2= \{\langle G \rangle \mid \text{L(G) } = \phi\}$$ is decidable for CFG. CFL is RE also. But why $L_1$ is undecidable but $L_2$ not, What's reason behind that?

Comment: `You know that Rice theorem is applicable to check decidability of RE language.` - what does it mean? Can you please give a link? Also, $L_2$ is not decidable too, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Universality for $\phi=\Sigma^*$.

Comment: Please use `\emptyset` for $\emptyset$. Also, again, please give a link for `applicable to decidability for RE language`; it’s my first time hearing about it.

Comment: Exactly which sentence makes you think that `Rice theorem is applicable to check decidability of RE language`? I suspect that you miss the point that Rice's theorem talks about languages consisting of Turing machines, and it doesn't say anything about languages generated by these machines. (Your hope is wrong!!!!!!!!!)

Comment: It doesn't seem to go anywhere, so I'm out. Looking at your other questions, you seem to be a beginner in this area, so I suggest you reconsider your conviction that you fully understand the theorem.

Comment: Rice's theorem is about languages of Turing machines. It doesn't apply to languages of context-free grammars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When domain is Unrestricted grammars i.e. $G$ can be any $Type-0$ grammar and then if it is asked "whether $L(G)$ is CFL or not" ....is Undecidable (Because of Rice's theorem) otherwise decidable. That's why $Q_1$ is undecidable and $Q_2$ is decidable.